# dynamic drop-down list using mysql php html causing undefined offset error

Tags: php, html, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBg15.jpg)i am getting error of undefined object while getting the drop-down list.[

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP DROP-DOWN</title>
  <meta  charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inintial-scale=1.0">
 </head>
 <body>
  <!--method1--->
   <select>
   <?php while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;?>
   <option value="<?php echo $row1[0];?>">
   <?php echo $row1[1];?>
   </option>
   <?php endwhile;?>
   </select>
 </body>
</html>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92u4L.jpg)

Comment: would you write the exact code message ?

Comment: Share what you get in `$result1` ?

Comment: notice:undefined offset :1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\final2.php

Comment: `while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;` <<< *That, kills it*

Comment: $connect = mysqli_connect ($hostname, $username, $password, $databasename);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `data1`";
$result1=mysqli_query($connect, $query);

Comment: then what should i write?@fred